Norm inequality for eigendecomposition and oblique projectors
Consider a stochastic matrix R which permits an eigendecomposition into oblique projectors,
$$R = \sum_{\lambda} \lambda C_{\lambda}$$
I've observed the following 2-norm inequality in a number of $R$ matrices that I've studied,
$$||R||^2_2 \le \sum_{\lambda} |\lambda|^2 ~ ||C_{\lambda}||^2_2$$
with $||A||^2_2 = Tr[A^\dagger A]$.
Notably, this identity doesn't hold for generic sums of matrices $R = A + B$,
$$||A + B||^2_2 = ||A||^2_2 + ||B||^2_2 + Tr[A^\dagger B + B^\dagger A]$$
but does seem to consistently hold for the eigendecompositions of stochastic matrices mentioned above.
Is this actually an identity?
Any key names or references would be appreciated, I've had a difficult time finding good resources for non-hermitian projectors and identities on them in general.

As an example, consider
$$P_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \alpha \
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$P_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -\alpha \
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
Then the matrix $R = P_1 + P_2$ is the identity matrix with squared 2-norm $2$. But each of $P_1$ and $P_2$ has squared 2-norm $1 + \alpha^2$, and the inequality holds.
